# Wget mirror site via ftp - timestamps issue

Tags: ftp, cron, wget, mirror

A site I'm working on requires a large amount of files to be downloaded from an external system via FTP, daily. This is not of my design, it is the only solution offered up by the external provider (I cannot use SSH/SFTP/SCP).

I've solved this by using wget, run inside a cron task:

```
wget -m -v -o log.txt --no-parent -nH -P /exampledirectory/ --user username --password password ftp://www.example.com/"
```

Unfortunately, wget does not seem to see the timestamp differences, so when a file is modified, it still returns:

> Remote file no newer than local file
>   `/xxx/data/data.file'
>   -- not retrieving.

When I manually connect via FTP, I can see differences in the timestamps, so it should be getting the updated file. I'm not able to access or control the target server via any other means.

Is there anything I can do to get around this? Can I force wget to mirror while ignoring timestamps? (I understand this defeats the point of mirroring)...

Comment: Does `--debug`  switch show anything useful?

Comment: this may sound quite stupid, but it's what has just happened to me and drove me mad last couple of hours : Did you check at the root directory of the user who the crontab belongs to ? In your case, let's say your crontab belongs to `joe`, didn't wget mirror the data in `~joe/www.example.com/` ?